# lookup list of websites, return security error PHP

Tags: php, ssl

I'd like to write a php script that will check a list of URLs in an array and return whether that URL resolves successfully or whether there is a security error.

Specifically I'm trying to detect the "this page is not secure" message that appears when you visit a site using https:// that doesn't have a valid SSL certificate.

So I figured I'd use a foreach loop to cycle through the array testing each URL. then echo either success, or error depending on whether it encounters a security error.

```
    $urls = array(
    'https://one.com',
    'https://two.com',
    'https://three.com'
    );

    foreach( $urls as $key => $value){
        //look up current domain name. if it resolves echo "success" 
        //else if an SSL error is encountered echo "error"
    }
```

Sorry I haven't gotten very far. Not sure where to start.
Does anyone know a simple way to do this?

thanks.

Comment: Even if you defined security error, this would be too broad for stackoverflow.  Keep your questions specific, show your work.

Comment: Apologies. I've defined the security error i am looking for and included what little working I have currently.

Comment: I can give you a hint.  The CURL library includes options to verify the certificate: http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php